# VC dimension of the class of polynomial classifiers of degree $n$

Tags: learning-theory, vc-dimension

I came across [this statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7fzw.png) on page 85 of the book ["understanding machine learning: from theory to algorithms"](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf)

### The general idea is as follows:

Consider a binary classiﬁcation problem with the instance domain being $X = \mathbb R$.

For every $n \in \mathbb N$ let $H_n$ be the class of polynomial classiﬁers of degree $n$; namely, $H_n$ is the set of all classiﬁers of the form $h(x) = \operatorname{sign}(p(x))$, where $p\colon  \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Prove that the VC dimension of $H_n$ is $n+1$.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I need to confirm that this claim is true. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Could you be more specific? As a first step, do you understand the concepts involved?

Comment: Of course I do. I have provided very specific background.

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Also, we're a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question about your task.  We're not looking for questions that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  Finally, I see that your task is quoted.  Please attribute the source of all copied or quoted material.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. By the way, the quote symbol is added by others, not me.

Comment: OK.  Well, regardless of what others may have added, where *did* you encounter this?  What was the original source where you saw this?  Did you copy from it?  Can you credit the original source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots, and so can change signs at most $n$ times. Therefore no polynomial of degree $n$ can form an alternating pattern +-+-... or -+-+... of length $n+2$. This shows that the VC dimension is at most $n+1$.

On the other hand, for any set of $n+1$ pairs $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$, there is a polynomial of degree $n$ which interpolates them, given by the Lagrange interpolation formula. Using $y_i = \pm 1$, you can easily show that *any* set of $n+1$ points is shattered. Therefore the VC dimension is exactly $n+1$.

Comment: If you can prove it, then it must be true.

Comment: If the proof works, then the result is true. You can try checking the special case $d=0$: see what the proof simplified to.

Comment: The polynomials $1$ and $-1$ shatter any single point.

Comment: The polynomials $1$ and $-1$ have degree $0$.

Comment: You can check this using the definition of VC dimension.

Comment: This seems correct. To be sure, you can prove it formally using the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof (not the only one). This proof appeals to the fact that our hypothesis class is a subset of a linear hypothesis class of degree $n+1$.

Let $\cal{P}_n$ denote the set of all d-degree polynomials $p_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Define the hypothesis class as follows:
$$
\cal{H}_{P_n} := \{ f_n : f_d(x) = \textbf{sign}(p_n(x)), \quad x \in \mathbb{R},\quad  p_n \in \cal{P}_n \}
$$

That is, $\cal{H}_{P_n}$ is the set of all d-degree classifiers.

We want to show that $VC(\cal{H}_{P_n}) = n + 1$. We will do so in two steps.

---

**Step 1**: Show that $VC(\cal{H}_{P_n}) \le n + 1$.

*Proof*: In this step, we are showing that $\cal{H}_{P_n}$ is a subset of the class of all linear classifiers $f_l:\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$.

That is, denote the class of all such linear classifiers as $\cal{H}_{l_{d+1}}:= \{f_l: f_l(x) = \textbf{sign}(\langle w, x \rangle), \quad w, x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\}$. Take as given that $VC(\cal{H}_{l_{n+1}}) = n + 1$.

Then, notice we can write any polynomial $p_n$ as a dot product between a vector of constants $c \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and a basis vector $\phi(x) :=\{1, x, x^2, \dots, x^n\}$, that is: $p_d(x) = \langle w, \phi(x) \rangle$.

Then, we can see that a polynomial is a type of linear function in the space of $\phi(x)$. Hence, (and you might need to do some thinking here to convince yourself),

$$
\cal{H}_{P_n} \subset \cal{H}_{l_{n+1}}
$$

Since the VC dimension of a smaller class of functions is less than or equal to the VC dimension of a greater class of functions,

$$
VC(\cal{H}_{P_n}) \le VC(\cal{H}_{l_{n+1}}) = n +1
$$

Hence, $VC(\cal{H}_{P_n}) \le n + 1$.

---

**Step 2**: Show that $VC(\cal{H}_{P_n}) \ge n + 1$.

*Proof*: The idea of this step is to show that $\cal{H}_{P_n}$ shatters *at least* $n + 1$ points. In order words, we want to show that we can find a set of $n+1$ points $\{x_1, x_2,...,x_{n+1}\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\{(f_d(x_1), f_d(x_2),\dots, f_d(x_{n+1}) ): f_d\in \cal{H}_{P_n}\}=\{-1,1\}^{n+1}$. (In other words, we can produce any possible label vector $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $y_i \in \{-1,1\} \forall i \in [n+1]$, using functions from our hypothesis class $\cal{H}_{P_n}$).

Here, you can use Vandermonte's Matrix Theorem that says that  the $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix produced by making columns out of $\phi(x_i), i \in [n+1]$ is invertible if and only if the $x_i$'s are all distinct (no duplicates). Writing this explicitly:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi(x_1) & \dots & \phi(x_{n+1})\\
\downarrow &  & \downarrow
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
x_1 & x_2 & \dots & x_{n+1}\\
x_1^2 & x_2^2 & \dots & x_{n+1}^2\\
\vdots &  & \dots & \vdots\\
x_1^{n+1} & x_2^{n+1} & \dots & x_{n+1}^{n+1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

That is to say, $\phi(x_1), \dots \phi(x_{n+1})$ are linearly independent, and since this is a square matrix, the rows are also linearly independent. Notice that the rows represent a single polynomial function when you pass a constant vector $c \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Therefore, the rows span $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. That is, for any point $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, there exists a unique solution $w\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $w_0 + w_1 x_i + w_2 x_i^2 + \dots + w_n x_i^n = v_i, \quad \forall i \in [n+1]$.

Moreover, this is true for a label vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. In other words, given a set of (distinct) points $\{x_1,\dots, x_{n+1}\}$ and associated (arbitrary) labels we can find weights $w \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ to create a d-degree polynomial $p_d$ that perfectly interpolates each point $y_i \in \{-1,1\}, \forall i \in [n+1]$.

Hence, $\cal{H}_{P_n}$ shatters $n+1$ points. Therefore, $VC(\cal{H}_{P_n}) \ge n + 1$.

---

**Step 3**: Show $VC(\cal{H}_{P_n}) = n + 1$.

*Proof*: By steps 1 and 2, it follows that $VC(\cal{H}_{P_n}) = n + 1$.

q.e.d.